# Calculating the average of an attribute for a points within a pixel

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point

[image]

I want to calculate the mean of an attribute of all points within each pixel.

For example, if there are two points within a pixel like in the lower left most corner shown, I want to calculate (attribute 1 of first point+attribute 1 of second point)/2

This is just one cluster of points, I have many more across the image and cannot do it manually.

Comment: Do you want to interpolate from these points to create a grid or are you specifically interested in altering the values of the existing grid using your point values?

Comment: @TrevorJ.Smith- I do not want to do any sort of interpolation or spatial statistics on the underlying raster. I just want to figure out a way to identify points in the same pixel, so that I can take the average of an attribute of those points.

Comment: Set extent,cell size and snap raster = raster. Convert point s to raster, raster to points, points to raster using pointid, raster to polygon.